How to permute the rows and cols of a matrix to maximize the set of pivots?
Given an $m\times n$ matrix $A$, how can I find permutations $\sigma,\tau$, such that for the matrix $B=A[\sigma,\tau]$ with shuffled columns and rows, the number of nonzero entries that have zeros below in their column and left in their row
$$f(B)=\big|\big\{(u,v)\in[m]\times[n];\, A[u,v]\neq0\text{ and }A[i,v]=0=A[u,j]\text{ for all }i\!<\!u,j\!>\!v\big\}\big|$$
is maximal?
If it helps, my matrices are very large and very sparse (e.g $10^6\times10^6$ with $10^8$ nonzeros). If this turns out to be a computationally difficult problem, how about at least providing a way to shuffle the cols and rows that produce very large $f(B)$?
My thought is: for row/col indices, compute vectors
$$\begin{align}
U=(\text{position of first nonzero entry in B[u,:]};u\in[m]),\\
V=(\text{position of last nonzero entry in B[:,v]};v\in[n]).
\end{align}$$
Then shuffle rows of $A$ to sort $U$ ascendingly and shuffle cols of $A$ to sort $V$ descendingly. For example:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
 ⋅&1&1&⋅&⋅&1&1&1&1&⋅\\
 ⋅&⋅&⋅&⋅&1&⋅&⋅&⋅&1&⋅\\
 ⋅&1&1&⋅&⋅&1&1&1&⋅&⋅\\
 ⋅&⋅&1&1&⋅&1&⋅&1&1&⋅\\
 ⋅&⋅&1&⋅&⋅&⋅&⋅&1&⋅&⋅\\
 ⋅&⋅&1&1&⋅&1&1&1&1&1\\
 ⋅&⋅&⋅&⋅&⋅&1&⋅&⋅&⋅&⋅\\
 ⋅&⋅&⋅&⋅&⋅&⋅&⋅&1&⋅&⋅\\
 1&1&⋅&⋅&1&1&⋅&⋅&⋅&⋅\\
 1&1&⋅&1&⋅&1&1&⋅&1&1\\
\end{bmatrix}\rightarrow
\begin{bmatrix}
 1&1&⋅&⋅&⋅&⋅&1&⋅&1&⋅\\
 1&1&⋅&1&1&1&⋅&1&1&⋅\\
 ⋅&1&1&⋅&1&⋅&⋅&1&1&1\\
 ⋅&1&1&⋅&1&⋅&⋅&⋅&1&1\\
 ⋅&⋅&1&1&⋅&⋅&⋅&1&1&1\\
 ⋅&⋅&1&⋅&⋅&⋅&⋅&⋅&⋅&1\\
 ⋅&⋅&1&1&1&1&⋅&1&1&1\\
 ⋅&⋅&⋅&⋅&⋅&⋅&1&1&⋅&⋅\\
 ⋅&⋅&⋅&⋅&⋅&⋅&⋅&⋅&1&⋅\\
 ⋅&⋅&⋅&⋅&⋅&⋅&⋅&⋅&⋅&1
\end{bmatrix}$$
Above, $f(A)=3$ and $f(B)=6$. This procedure can even be applied repeatedly. This gives decent results (though not maximal), but I was hoping for something better.
